# Can I Mount an external hard drive as a network drive?

Tags: windows, macos, external-hard-drive, nas

is there any way to make a Mac think my external hard drive is a network drive?

Basically I need a USB/Thunderbolt Drive to be recognised as a network drive on my Mac since the program (Avid Media Composer) I'm trying to use treats local and network drives differently.

If anyone knows how to do it on Windows I'll be happy with that!

Answer (score 0):

On Windows its very easy.  Simply [share](https://www.tomshardware.com/news/how-to-share-drives-windows-pc,36936.html) the drive, then you can mount the share as a network drive.

I am sure you can do the same thing on a Mac.

Comment: Why did someone "-1" this answer?? (I gave it back).  WINDOWS bigotry? . ***"If anyone knows how to do it on Windows I'll be happy with that!"** was part of the question.  Grow up people. ALL computers suck.